# regular expression, grab link

Tags: php, expression

I have html document and links, like `http://example.com/some?b=20130218082149&a=20130218092249&info=1152&hash=079caaaae2fcd602c6d8dx`

I need a regular expression to find it, and if you can explain the expression to me, that'd be really helpful.

Comment: [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) is not a `Hello all` topic maker, as the domain name suggests what is all about. You need someone to make it for you? You have to try something first and then maybe someone will point out your errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My stab at it**

```
<?php

$pattern = "#^https?://([a-z0-9-]+\.)*blah\.com(/.*)?$#";

$tests = array(
    'http://blah.com/so/this/is/good'
  , 'http://blah.com/so/this/is/good/index.html'
  , 'http://www.blah.com/so/this/is/good/mice.html#anchortag'
  , 'http://anysubdomain.blah.com/so/this/is/good/wow.php'
  , 'http://anysubdomain.blah.com/so/this/is/good/wow.php?search=doozy'
  , 'http://any.sub-domain.blah.com/so/this/is/good/wow.php?search=doozy' // I added this case
  , 'http://999.sub-domain.blah.com/so/this/is/good/wow.php?search=doozy' // I added this case
  , 'http://obviousexample.com'
  , 'http://bbc.co.uk/blah.com/whatever/you/get/the/idea'
  , 'http://blah.com.example'
  , 'not/even/a/blah.com/url'
);

foreach ( $tests as $test )
{
  if ( preg_match( $pattern, $test ) )
  {
    echo $test, " <strong>matched!</strong><br>";
  } else {
    echo $test, " <strong>did not match.</strong><br>";
  }
}

//  Here's another way
echo '<hr>';
foreach ( $tests as $test )
{
  if ( $filtered = filter_var( $test, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL ) )
  {
    $host = parse_url( $filtered, PHP_URL_HOST );
    if ( $host && preg_match( "/blah\.com$/", $host ) )
    {
      echo $filtered, " <strong>matched!</strong><br>";
    } else {
      echo $filtered, " <strong>did not match.</strong><br>";
    }
  } else {
    echo $test, " <strong>did not match.</strong><br>";
  }
}
```